# Graal VM components required for a Node calling Java polyglot application

Tags: graalvm, polyglot, graaljs

I planning to GraalVM to **merge two (services one using Node and other based on Java) with Node as the main entry point language which calls classes/constructs in Java**.  I was reading about GraalVM but was not able to find below information in clarty. It will be great if someone can help me with this (or point out if I am missing/overlooking something)

1. **What are the bare minimum GraalVM components required for above use case** ?
   I know that Graal VM has core and optional components. Do we require entire GraalVM including the hotspot VM for this use case or **just below components are sufficient ?(please add/correct I am missing some components)**. **I perfer to use OpenJDK8 as my JVM**

   - GraalJS
   - GraalSDK
   - Truffle

   Correct me If I am wrong - My understanding for coming up with above components are that - GraalJS contains node/js run time implemented over truffle and supporting polyglot and has node modules which contains polyglot api. GraalSDK - contains polyglot api for Java. Truffle has the logic to convert JS to bytecode which runs on JVM
2. **Is there any clear documentation on how each of this module work together ?**
   I am looking for a small/abstract diagram/flow-diagaram which tells how GraalJS , GraalSDK & Truffle and underlying JVM work together to achieve polyglotness. This helps further understand and pinpoint which components are required for my usecase

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

regarding the **first question**: your assumption would be correct if you only used "pure" JavaScript (ECMAScript 2020). Then, only the `GraalVM Compiler` is missing from your list. If you omit that, you can technically execute the JavaScript interpreter, but it will be very slow. To allow the `Truffle` component to do its magic of speeding up the application, you will need the GraalVM Compiler. See our blogpost https://medium.com/graalvm/graalvms-javascript-engine-on-jdk11-with-high-performance-3e79f968a819 how to set that up on a stock JDK (like OpenJDK) using Maven.

In your case, you want to use Node.js though. For that you need a full Node.js distribution including Graal.js - only a full GraalVM will provide that.

For your **second question**: I don't know of a good graphic that describes the GraalVM SDK. For Truffle and language implementation in general, https://docs.oracle.com/en/graalvm/enterprise/19/guide/overview/jvm-runtime-model.html might be a good starting point. There are also several good tutorials on YouTube on GraalVM+Truffle.

Best,
Christian